# Python: CircularQueue print items from begin to end of Queue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to implement Circular Queue in python and trying implement **str**(self) that print all the elements from the queue from the beginning to the end.When I print out the list, it does not give the whole list of items in the queue.

I am splicing the items from the self.items from the front and going till the end of the list.

```
class CircularQueue:
    def __init__(self,capacity):

        self.items =[None]*capacity
        self.MAX_QUEUE = capacity
        self.front = 0
        self.back = self.MAX_QUEUE - 1
        self.count = 0

    def is_full(self):
        return self.count == self.MAX_QUEUE

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.count == 0

    def enqueue(self,item):
            if not self.is_full():
                self.back = (self.back+1)%self.MAX_QUEUE
                self.items[self.back] = item
                self.count +=1
            else:
               raise IndexError("The queue is full.")
    def dequeue(self):
            if not self.is_empty():
                item = self.items[self.front]
                self.front =(self.front+1)% self.MAX_QUEUE
                self.count -=1
                return item
            else:
                raise IndexError("The queue is empty.")

    def peek(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            item = self.items[self.front]
            return item
        else:
            raise IndexError("The queue is empty.")
    def __str__(self):
        my_list = []
        for i in self.items[self.front:]:
            my_list.append(i)
        return str(my_list)


q = CircularQueue(8)
q.enqueue(5)
q.enqueue(2)
q.enqueue(1)
q.enqueue(7)
q.enqueue(9)
q.dequeue()
q.dequeue()
q.dequeue()
q.dequeue()
q.dequeue()
q.enqueue(2)
q.enqueue(4)
q.enqueue(1)
q.enqueue(7)
q.enqueue(6)
q.enqueue(3)
print(q)

Expected result:
[2, 4, 1, 7, 6, 3]
Got:
[2,4,1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that you only add in the elements from the `front` of the circular array to the end of the underlying list implementation. What you really want to do is copy from `front` to end, and then from beginning to `back`.

This gives me the correct output

```
def __str__(self):
    my_list = []
    for i in self.items[self.front:]:
        my_list.append(i)

    for i in self.items[:self.back+1]:
        my_list.append(i)

    return str(my_list)
```

Hope that helps! Also, you might want to consider using `cycle` from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).